# subscribe value undefined outside when assign to a variable in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I am getting undefined value when assigning the subscribed value to a variable.
Here is my code.

**service.ts**

```
     getIpAddress() : Observable<any> 
     {
      return this.http
      .get(this.Geo_Api)
      .map((response: Response) => {  return <any>response.json() 
      } )
      .catch(this.handleError);
      }
```

**component.ts**

```
 constructor(private apiservice: ApiService )
 {
   this.getIpAddress(); 

 }
 ngOnInit() {  console.log(this.client_ip$);   } 

 getIpAddress()
 {

    this.apiservice.getIpAddress()
    .subscribe(data => {
    this.client_data$       =   data.ip;
    this.client_ip$     =   this.client_data$; 
  });

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the service without injecting it to the component.

```
constructor(private apiservice: Apiservice)
```

Comment: its used. I forgot to add in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(private apiservice: ApiService )
{


}
 ngOnInit() {    this.getIpAddress();   } // call service in ngOnInit();

getIpAddress()
{

 this.apiservice.getIpAddress()
.subscribe(data => {
this.client_data$       =   data.ip;
this.client_ip$     =   this.client_data$; 

// as service is async call try console in subscirbe callback
this.useClient()
});

}
useClient(){
console.log(this.client_ip$);
}
```

Comment: I want to use the value outside subscribe. How to assign the subscribe value to a variable.?

Comment: you can use it once the service sets this.client_ip$ else it will print undefined.
You can see the edited answer

Comment: i see the $ on your class properties, are you using these as observables?